# Check state of multiple checkboxes against an array

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm given an array and I need to filter records against the state of multiple groups of checkboxes and then check my array to see if it contains the value of one of the corresponding values that match the checkbox that is checked. I need to do this with about 10 different groups of checkboxes...of which two are shown below. Another caveat is that let's say there are 3 checkboxes shown in the first one now, but there may be 4 next year if the customer thinks of more criteria. So I'd like something that keeps me from changing the code when new checkboxes are added. Is there a better way to do this or do I just need to go down each checkbox group checking against the array like below?

```
var showRecord = false;

// 3 at this time...but could be more one day.
if (checkboxDevelopment.Checked && myArray[10].ToString() == "Development")
    || (checkboxStaging.Checked && myArray[10].ToString() == "Staging"
    || (checkboxProduction.Checked && myArray[10].ToString() == "Production")
{
    showRecord = true;
}
else
{
    showRecord = false;
}

// If the 1st test passed, keep checking.
if (showRecord)
{
    // 4 in this group...but could be more one day.
    if (checkboxPass.Checked && myArray[11].ToString() == "Pass")
        || (checkboxFail.Checked && myArray[11].ToString() == "Fail"
        || (checkboxUnknown.Checked && myArray[11].ToString() == "Unknown"
        || (checkboxError.Checked && myArray[11].ToString() == "Error")
    {
        showRecord = true;
    }
    else
    {
        showRecord = false;
    }

}

// A bunch more checkboxes to go through until I can decide if to show the record or not.
...

if (showRecord)
{
    // Code to show the record in the user's search results.
}
```

Comment: If _myArray_ is an array of strings there is no need to call ToString for each element

Comment: Unless I was seeing things, didn't you have an answer here earlier?

Comment: It was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is this:
If you do follow a naming convention as in your snippet and put each group of checkboxes into their own group, you could try something like this:

```
 var showRecord = false;
        foreach (CheckBox item in checkboxGroup1)
        {
            if (item.Checked && myArray[10].ToString()==item.Name.ToString().Substring(8))
            {
                showRecord = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

So you iterate through the checkbox group and if any of the checkboxes is selected + the name is correct, then it will set showRecord to true and break the loop.
Then repeat for each group of check boxes.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you...that is a good way to approach it without having to worry how many checkboxes I have.